# Using Kolmogorv's inequality to prove Law of large numbers

Tags: probability-theory

So, I want to prove LLS, and im following the steps of the proof.

One of the steps (actually the last one) is the following:

Let $ \left(X_{n}\right)_{n} $ be independent such that $ \mathbb{E}[X_{n}]=0 $ and $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}Var[X_{n}]<\infty $. Prove that $ \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}X_{k}\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace converge\thinspace\thinspace\right)=1 $.

Now, it sufficies to show that for $ S_{n}:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k} $,

$ \mathbb{P}\left(S_{n}\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace is\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace a\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace Cauchy\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace sequence\right)=1 $.

So, for any $ n \in \mathbb{N} $ , $ m>0 $ and a fixed $ \lambda>0 $ we have by Kolomogorv's inequality:

$ \mathbb{P}\left(\max_{1\leq k\leq m}|S_{n+k}-S_{n}|\geq\lambda\right)\leq\frac{1}{\lambda^{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\mathbb{E}[X_{n+k}^{2}]\leq\frac{1}{\lambda^{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_{n+k}^{2}] $

Now the RHS does not depend on $ m $ and therefore I can take the limit where $ m \to \infty $ from both sides:

$ \lim_{m\to\infty}\left(\max_{1\leq k\leq m}|S_{n+k}-S_{n}|\geq\lambda\right)\leq\frac{1}{\,\lambda^{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_{n+k}^{2}] $

Since we have increasing sequence of events, by continuity of probability we have:

$ \mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{k\geq1}\max_{1\leq k\leq m}|S_{n+k}-S_{n}|\geq\lambda\right)\leq\frac{1}{\lambda^{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_{n+k}^{2}] $

Now here's my question. What can I say about  $ \bigcup_{k\geq1}\max_{1\leq k\leq m}|S_{n+k}-S_{n}|\geq\lambda $ ?

Is it possible that actually:

$ \bigcup_{k\geq1}\max_{1\leq k\leq m}|S_{n+k}-S_{n}|\geq\lambda=\bigcup_{k\geq1}|S_{n+k}-S_{n}|\geq\lambda $?

If so, I dont understand why the $ \max $ was needed (and therefore why Kolmogorov was needed).

Thanks in advance.